# Searching Storage Account with Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-explorer

Using Log Analytics, is it possible to search thru data stored in a container inside an Azure storage account? We have an Azure Function that reaches out to an API in O365 for log data and then it pushes that data into a storage account. We would like to be able to query this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can push content inside your container to log analytics workspace repository using something called log analytics http data collector API.
We need to build your own integration of sending container content to log analytics by leveraging http data collector API.

You may refer to the suggestion mentioned in the article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api

Additional information: - Azure Functions
- Azure Automation
- Logic App
With any of these what you will do is have some schedule that will run on certain interval. When it is ran you will execute query against Log Analytics to get data. The results from the query you will transfer to Azure Storage may be as blob. You might have to do some transformation on the data depending on your scenario. The most important that you have to make sure is that you do not miss data or upload the same data twice to the storage.  Log Analytics query language allows you to specify time frame for the results. I hope this will help you.

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.